# BULK INSERT into SQL Server - using FIELDTERMINATOR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query:

```
BULK INSERT Employee
FROM 'E:\\file.txt' --location with filename
WITH
(
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

And in the my file, the data looks like this:

```
43266200 6827           43295200 1393/05/23 14:26:26     18      1
```

I want insert this data into my table, but in file in the my fieldterminator have a error and SQL Server complains about space or tab between fields error. How can I solve this?
can i use this?

```
BULK INSERT Employee
    FROM 'E:\\file.txt' --location with filename
    WITH
    (
       FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ' or '  ' or '        ',
       ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
    GO
```

or how can i import this txt file into sql server?

Comment: `FROM 'E:\\file.txt'` Is this the actual SQL you're running or are you trying to extract it from your C# source code, sans `"`? Because it looks like the latter. In which case, pay attention to the *actual* SQL statement being run.

Comment: i think between the field in my file has a tab space and simple space for example 43266200space6827\t43295200

Answer (score 4):

If you have a tab between your fields in the data file, then use this:

```
BULK INSERT Employee
FROM 'E:\\file.txt' --location with filename
WITH
(
   FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

The `\t` denotes a tab - that should tell SQL Server to interpret a tab as a separator between two fields.

Comment: thanks for attention to my problem,but my friend in the my file for example between the 43266200 and 6827 field have a 3 space and between   6827 and 43295200 have a \t

Comment: and when your query run in my sql server:

Comment: Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)". error

Comment: You need to *clean* your file before importing - you cannot have three spaces in one place, and a tab in another. This has to be **consistent** throughout the file!

Comment: but my file has 27000000 record! how can i clean record in big txt file?

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi Revise the routine that made you the `file.txt` to only export with tabs as delimiters. If you can't revise that routine, you will have to write a programme to sanitize the field seperators in `file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
BULK INSERT #ProspectiveFile
                  FROM ''C:\Matt\' + @DataFileName + '.txt''
                  WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
                       ,FIELDTERMINATOR = ''    '')
```